# How do I change the Data source into Microsoft SQL Server in Visual C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I was using this [tutorial](http://razibdeb.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/sql-server-2008-basics-connection-with-vs2010/) and I'm stuck in this [part](http://razibdeb.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/ms-sql.png). The guide tells me to choose 'Microsoft SQL Server', however this is not included in the options of my computer. I only have 'Microsoft Database File', 'Microsoft Server Compact', and 'Microsoft Database Server File'.

How could I add the option 'Microsoft SQL Server'?

Comment: what version of VS your are using?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the express version can natively connect to SQL server. I can't seem to find any documentation on this, but if I recall correctly it was one of the reasons we switched to pro way back when. Anyways, perhaps this post will help: [How to connect Visual Studio 2010 Express C# to SQL Server Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847688/how-to-connect-visual-studio-2010-express-c-sharp-to-sql-server-express)

Answer (score 1):

If yours is a web application, then you can do it the way its shown in your tutorial,

but if yours is a Winforms of WPF application you can't do it with Visual Studio Express..

There are other ways to connect using SqlConnection, SqlCommand objects etc, which are not design time..you can use them however..

Answer (score 0):

please select option **other** from that [part](http://razibdeb.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/ms-sql.png)  and then select ".NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server" from that list. please try let me know

Comment: I don't have the 'other' option too.

Comment: Since you are visual studio express 2010, you might not have that option. Please install the VS2010 professional after downloading from the internet

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are missing some component try to download http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx